# How to parse a Crystal Report in .NET and display all its objects?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report. I want to read this report as an object when I provide the path to a VB.NET application and be able to read all the object properties.

I tried to find the APIs but I couldn't succeed. And I am very new to VB.NET even though I have worked on Crystal Reports using tool.

Any help is appreciated. Kindly help me.

Best Regards
Gowtham

Answer (score 0):

see [rpttoxml](http://code.google.com/p/rpttoxml/)

Comment: But the XML and XSD are used to represent data. I would like to know the properties of the object. For example there is a text object used in report. I want to know what is the position (x,y), height, width and other such properties details. Is this possible with the same?

Comment: The height and width are available.  These properties are either available on the ReportObject (base class)--see the GetReportObjects() method.  Additional properties are available on each descendant (e.g. DatabaseFieldDefinition, ParameterFieldDefinition), but these are specific to each descendant.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.